# Java Web Start: Signed Jar without APPLICATION.JNLP launches via JNLP since 8u91

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start

maybe it's a beginner's fault:

I have a signed jar file (no JNLP-INF\APPLICATION.JNLP) and an external JNLP I start. The application is not allowed to run with JRE <= 8u77. It only works with a copy of the external JNLP as JNLP-INF\APPLICATION.JNLP in the jar file (as documented).

But with JRE >= 8u91 there is no copy of the JNLP inside the jar needed. The application launches as usual.

The JNLP has the all-permissions tag.

Bug or feature?

Comment: *a copy of the external JNLP as JNLP-INF\APPLICATION.JNLP in the jar file* if it's in the jar file, how is it external?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Afaik you need one copy to launch the application. That is the one I refer to as external.